# manual bit reverse for binary numbers

Tags: binary, reverse, bit

I have been tasked with manually bit reversing a series of binary numbers. As I have not been taught this I have been trying to find tutorials, however all the tutorials are using a programming language, and I need to do this with Pen and Paper. Can anyone help with this? Is this just a mirror image of the original binary number?

Comment: "Is this just a mirror image of the original binary number?". Yes.

Comment: @jamesKPolk - Thanks for this. This has also helped with 1's complement and the differences